# Wait for first task in array to match a condition

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a `Task<bool>[] myTasks`. How do I get notified (await) when the first `Task` returns `true` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, you need to keep a set of incomplete tasks, and repeatedly use `Task.WhenAny`, check the result, and keep going (having removed that task) if the result wasn't what you were looking for. For example:

```
ISet<Task<bool>> activeTasks = new HashSet<Task<bool>>(myTasks);
while (activeTasks.Count > 0)
{
    Task<bool> completed = await Task.WhenAny(activeTasks);
    if (completed.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
        completed.Result)
    {
        // Or take whatever action you want
        return;
    }
    // Task was faulted, cancelled, or had a result of false.
    // Go round again.
    activeTasks.Remove(completed);
}
// No successful tasks - do whatever you need to here.
```

Comment: Continuous calling of `Task.WhenAny`, till we achieve the first valid true Task, that's what I was thinking, was trying to find an overload, which can do it, but there's none, thanks @Jon for the great solution. 
Nonetheless why Hashset, we can simply work with an array, what if a  duplicate tasks are fine in an array

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: You need to be able to remove the completed task that you've already checked from the collection that you pass to `WhenAny` - otherwise it will immediately return and give you the same task again. You can't remove items from an array. I've suggested using `HashSet` so that the tasks can be found and removed in O(1) rather than O(n), although unless you have a *lot* of tasks, the difference between that and a `List<Task<bool>>` is probably insignificant.

Comment: Why do you check completed.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion after Task.WhenAny(activeTasks);? Would be nice to have that as a lamba extension or something, I might try that later if you dont bother to do.

Comment: Wouldn't Hashset, remove in O(logn), instead of O(1), since, it is still not Key value pair, so its O(logn) vs O(n)

Comment: @Milleu: Because the task might have been cancelled or faulted instead of successful.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Um, no - it's still a key, looked up with a hash lookup. You can think of a `HashSet` as a `Dictionary` where the value doesn't matter...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for clear explanation, but then if we do a `Contains` search on Hashset that does in O(logn), vis-a-vis O(1) of Dictionary `ContainsKey`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: No, it should be O(1). What makes you think it's O(log n)? At this point, we're a bit off the topic of the question - if you're still confused, it may be worth you asking a new question, with whatever reason you have to think it's O(log n). Perhaps you're thinking of `SortedSet`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I need to check I read it somewhere, since it arrange data internally in a Binary search Tree, but may be I have not understood correctly.